# Change action type away from "smart home"

Tags: actions-on-google

Hope someone can help me - I was exploring the action options at https://console.actions.google.com/u/0/ and did the following:

1) Created a project and selected my Firebase project from the drop-down (which linked my Firebase project to the actions console).

2) Created a new action and chose "smart home" (which I regret)

3) Went through the motions of setting up the action, but when I got to the testing page and realized that this was for a smart home device... I wanted to bail out and change the "type" of action.

But no where (I mean no where) is there a place for me to delete this action and move away from it being a smart home action. I cannot create any other actions on my project.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want a different project type you should create a new project. You can also [delete the existing project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects).

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer... I do not want to delete the project. I want to change the existing project type to non-smart home.

Comment: And, even though it is true I can create a new project... I can no longer associate that project with my Firebase project because the Firebase project is already associated with the smart home action...